# SSO with ADFS using WS Federation working fine on localhost but not on server

Tags: model-view-controller, single-sign-on, adfs, ws-federation

We want to implement SSO in our multiple application 
 
eg : **abc.domain.com/app1** and **abc.domain.com/app2**.

We have configured ADFS on our server. WE have used WS federation authentication. Our both app are aware of claim based authentication.

Scenario we want to achieve,
**1.** Make login on app **abc.domain.com/app1** using ADFS WS federation authentication.
**2.** We have successfully authenticated in this domain.
**3.** Now make request on **abc.domain.com/app2**. It should be login automatically in this app.

### Actioned:

- Both app URLs are added on relying party trust in ADFS.
- We have added Endpoint URL of 1st app  abc.domain.com/app1
- Both app refer same ADFS metadata URL.

We have achieved this in our local environment. In local system these two different app are running on different port 
1. localhost:44313 
 
2. localhost:44330

When we make successfully login on **localhost:44313** and request on **localhost:44330** then user also authenticated for this app as well and displayed as logged in.

This scenario is not working fine for the live environment. Our live URL structure is same as mentioned above (abc.domain.com/app1, abc.domain.com/app2) but it's not working there.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: More details on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110049/not-able-to-achieve-single-sign-on-with-adfss-multiple-applications

Answer (score 1):

What errors do you see in the event log?

If you have two different apps, you need two different RP on ADFS.

Also you need to run both on https.

Do you have https on your live environment?

Comment: Also we are running both app on https. We have a single template of Relying Party trust and added both app URLs in same RP. Do we need to create separate RP?

Comment: Yes - that's what you normally do.

Comment: Thanks. We have not achieved what we want but this option worked as alternative solution.